# Android Spin/Rotate gesture not working correctly?

Tags: java, android

Bear with me, as I am not a fully fledged android expert, the person who created the code has left the company, and I am trying to update the app for newer devices, it's a game whereby you can spin with your finger, and it continues to spin for a short while (unless you keep turning it, like a fidget spinner where it would spin faster and faster).
However, whilst the gesture works to rotate it, the minute you lift your finger from the screen, it stops, so it's not continuing to spin.

Here are some useful parts of the code;

```
int DURATION_FOR_ONE_ROTATION = 300;
```

```
 private class MyOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        private double startAngle;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (rotationAnimator != null && rotationAnimator.isRunning()) {
                rotationAnimator.cancel();
            } else {

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        for (int i = 0; i < quadrantTouched.length; i++) {
                            quadrantTouched[i] = false;
                        }
                        allowRotating = false;
                        startAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        double currentAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        rotateDialer((float) (startAngle - currentAngle));
                        startAngle = currentAngle;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        allowRotating = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            quadrantTouched[getQuadrant(event.getX() - (dialerWidth / 2), dialerHeight - event.getY() - (dialerHeight / 2))] = true;
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
            //Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"onDown: " + event.toString());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            //Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onScroll: " + event1.toString() + event2.toString());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
            super.onShowPress(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            int q1 = getQuadrant(e1.getX() - (dialerWidth / 2), dialerHeight - e1.getY() - (dialerHeight / 2));
            int q2 = getQuadrant(e2.getX() - (dialerWidth / 2), dialerHeight - e2.getY() - (dialerHeight / 2));
            float velocity = (velocityX + velocityY) * 3;
            int rotationTime = (int) (velocity / 360) * DURATION_FOR_ONE_ROTATION;

            if ((q1 == 2 && q2 == 2 && Math.abs(velocityX) < Math.abs(velocityY))
                    || (q1 == 3 && q2 == 3)
                    || (q1 == 1 && q2 == 3)
                    || (q1 == 4 && q2 == 4 && Math.abs(velocityX) > Math.abs(velocityY))
                    || ((q1 == 2 && q2 == 3) || (q1 == 3 && q2 == 2))
                    || ((q1 == 3 && q2 == 4) || (q1 == 4 && q2 == 3))
                    || (q1 == 2 && q2 == 4 && quadrantTouched[3])
                    || (q1 == 4 && q2 == 2 && quadrantTouched[3])) {
                rotateWheelToTarget(dialer, 0, -1 * velocity, Utils.getUnsignedInt(rotationTime), 0);
            } else {
                rotateWheelToTarget(dialer, 0, velocity, Utils.getUnsignedInt(rotationTime), 0);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    float getDistance(float startX, float startY, MotionEvent ev) {
        float distanceSum = 0;
        final int historySize = ev.getHistorySize();
        for (int h = 0; h < historySize; h++) {
            float hx = ev.getHistoricalX(0, h);
            float hy = ev.getHistoricalY(0, h);
            float dx = (hx - startX);
            float dy = (hy - startY);
            distanceSum += Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            startX = hx;
            startY = hy;
        }
        float dx = (ev.getX(0) - startX);
        float dy = (ev.getY(0) - startY);
        distanceSum += Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return distanceSum;
    }
```

I was hoping it would continue spinning

Comment: i'm hoping your question isn't related to actual device rotation. so when you lift the finger, action stops. write another function to 'manually' rotate animate the graphic object in question. lets say the function rotates the object slowly stopping to 0. invoke this function in the pointer up section.